# Why the quotes in this sentence about Soylent: designed from the “ground-up”?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Why is "ground-up" in quotes [here](http://techcrunch.com/2015/08/03/soylent-debuts-its-ready-to-drink-meal-replacement-drink-soylent-2-0/?ncid=rss)? As far as I understand this phrase means "from the beginning", so the company designed the whole recipe itself.

> But with the addition of a ready-made blend, which the company describes as being designed *from the “ground-up”* with a combination of the vitamins, minerals, fats, carbohydrates and protein that the body needs, Soylent is targeting a slightly different demographic.

Comment: Hard to say without context.  This may be a quote from company propaganda or it may be scare quotes to indicate that the product wasn't literally compounded from basic elements or it is intended to make sure that readers don't confuse the term with grinding material up.

Comment: The hyphen in "ground-up" is also incorrect.

Comment: Yeah, absent the movie allusion, the quotes and hyphen are wrong, but it (sorta) makes sense (in a stupid sort of way) if you consider the movie.

Comment: @phoog, without context you can't tell but "ground-up" is an adjective and takes the hyphen. The noun is omitted for deliberate ambiguity as the original reference is to ground-up people, now it's to unspecified ingredients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just as @deadrat said in the comment above. Ground up does indeed mean from the beginning, but *ground-up* means ground, as in hamburger.

Soylent is a food replacement drink named after the movie "Soylent Green", in which people unknowingly ate processed humans.

They are kind of ghoulish about it themselves, though it is (presumably) a soy-based food replacement.

Soy food-replacement named Soylent? "Ground-up" is in quotes to underscore it's "roots", a play on words reflecting a particularly telling scene in *Soylent Green*.

> Venture-backed food replacement drink maker [Soylent – yes, named after the movie where people unknowingly were sustained by eating other people](http://techcrunch.com/2015/08/03/soylent-debuts-its-ready-to-drink-meal-replacement-drink-soylent-2-0/?ncid=rss) – is out today with its newest product. The company this morning introduced “Soylent 2.0” (still not people), which is actually a vegan, soy-based nutritional drink that’s now shipping in a ready-to-drink package.

Soylent 2.0's [promo photo](http://www.forbes.com/sites/briansolomon/2015/08/03/soylent-2-0-why-soylent-is-hitting-the-bottle/) even has a question mark on the bottom of a mysteriously blank white plastic bottle.

Comment: At least I thought I remembered it. It's been, what? 40 years or so?